# Xamarin App on visual studio 2013 crashing

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013

Currently deploying an app on visual studio 2013 that consume a webs service

I can deploy it to my android emulator - Android_Acceleratedx86:5554 but when i run the app it just crashes how do i see the error log to look for the error that is happening and how do i solve it?

I was able to deploy an app successfully some time ago but this crashes just started today even in an new clean app that i created and deploy without changes.

I tested it on my Android mobile phone Samsung Note 3 also has the same result need some advice on this.

EDIT: Got the error Log out

> 01-12 14:28:28.035: E/art(3452): Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of
>   14): Broken pipe
>
> 01-12 14:28:28.107: E/Surface(1888): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown
>   buffer: 0xaecb2c00
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452): Process: App5.App5, PID:
>   3452
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 01-12 14:28:29.006:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   ... 1 more
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452): Caused by:
>   android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   App5.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0003f] in
>   <29230c8833f94d0588725602e0a39395>:0
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr
>   jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in
>   :0
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at (wrapper
>   dynamic-method) System.Object:85292671-94af-4f90-9e0e-73f86f2d0ef5
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   md593b8d625023f6802361dd1b8a6546be5.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native
>   Method)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   md593b8d625023f6802361dd1b8a6546be5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>
> 01-12 14:28:29.006: E/AndroidRuntime(3452):   ... 3 more
>
> 01-12 14:28:30.657: E/Surface(1413): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown
>   buffer: 0x9d9857e0
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/BluetoothAdapter(1413): Bluetooth binder is null
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413): Failed to read
>   cpu-freq
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed:
>   ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:103) 01-12
>   14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):   at
>   java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:66)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413): Caused by:
>   android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelCpuSpeedReader(1413):     ... 11 more
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413): Failed to read
>   uid_cputime
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat: open
>   failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:103)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:66)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413): Caused by:
>   android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader(1413):   ... 11 more
>
> 01-12 14:29:10.637: E/KernelWakelockReader(1413): neither
>   /proc/wakelocks nor /d/wakeup_sources exists

can i have some help on what is the main error causing the crashes?

Sorry i gt no idea how to shorten this error log

Comment: use the adb tools to view the device/emulator logs

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` hints that you have a null reference somewhere.

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x6611KCAzs) was following this tutorial and other apps such as simple hello world which worked before is not working now

Answer (score 1):

If you have Android Studio or even just the Android SDK, you can monitor the logcat output using the debug bridge.

Using the SDK, open `<SDK Directory>\tools\monitor.bat` (Assuming you use Windows)
And Android Studio should already have a logcat view open. If not, 
I believe it can be enabled in the View menu.

Be sure to set the logcat output to "Error Only" to make it easier to see when they occur.

Also. Make sure your emulator is seen by ADB, if not, enable developer options and turn on USB debugging.

Hope this helps.